# Making Regular Expression SQL Anywhere

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regular expression to match some specific strings.

Regular expression: `(A[\s.AVC]+)`

For example:

[image]

I need only the words at leading of string like this:

```
"AA",
"AAVV",
"A.",
"AVENIDA",
"A.V",
"AA VV"
```

But it sometimes matches more words per line. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The regular expression is perfect but SQL Anywhere don't admit \b (boundary) in the pattern. #FML

Comment: `regexp_substr(column_name_table, '(\bA[\s.AVENIDAC]+\b)')` it returns null value. 
And \b is for Matches a backspace character.

Answer (score 1):

You can use special character `^` at the start of the regex, so it always finds occurrences from the start of the line.

[More information here](http://regexone.com/lesson/10)

Comment: Yeah, I tried put the character ^ too but it doesn't works.
Picture: http://imgur.com/LZEmwfL

Comment: Gotcha!!! Just delete the character ^ and that's it.

Picture: http://i.imgur.com/vi3OjEw.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use anchor `^` to force you regex engine match the pattern from start also you need a word boundary :

```
(^\bA[\s.AVC]+\b)
```

And in SQL you can use `[[:<:]]`, `[[:>:]]` for word boundaries :

```
(^[[:<:]]A[\s.AVC]+[[:>:]])
```

Comment: Very helpful, but still doesnt match all occurrences

Comment: @SacrilegeTx So whats the problem?

Comment: How can I explain it?
The database at work the entries for address is like the image above, so I need some regular expression to format that entries. For example:
If the regular expression found the words: "AA" "AA VV" "A." "A.V" and more I'wll replace those words for: "AV." and so on.

Comment: Now the regular expression created works perfectly on [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com) but not the same case on Interactive SQL: `regexp_substr(column_name_table, '(\bA[\s.AVENIDAC]+\b)')` the problem is `\b` character,  for Debuggex means Boundary and for Interactive means BackSpace.

Comment: This is a headache!!!
Well, check this out. I think got something with this expression: `(A[\s\.:\-VENIDAC]+)(\s|$|\.)`
[Image Here](http://i.imgur.com/ZNFvRkY.jpg)
Now some issues, for example the following strings:
_AV. V.R. HAYA DE LA TORRE_: error because the expression takes to **V.**
_AV. VENECIA DISTR. JOSE SABOGAL_: error because it takes to **VENECIA**
_AA.HH. 22 DE AGOSTO - SAN IGNACIO_: error cuz it takes **AA.** but **AA.HH** means _human settlement_ (English) but is an acronym here in Perú.
How many cases will found? :lol:

Comment: And btw, ur code: [Error](http://i.imgur.com/YeKJLe3.jpg) Details: `Invalid regular expression: invalid character class in
'(^[[:<:]]A[\s.AVC]+[[:>:]])'
SQLCODE=-1135, ODBC 3 State="2201B"`